# Can Guava’s TypeToken get the specific type of a generic field?

Tags: java, guava

I wrote a parser for a file format called ASN.1 that uses Guice’s `TypeLiteral.getFieldType(Field)` to convert generic fields into specific Java types so I can construct the correct type (similar to Jackson or GSON databinding). But since I already depend on Guava and it seems to have a new TypeLiteral replacement, I’d like to use `TypeToken` instead. According to the [Guave TypeToken documentation](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained):

> `TypeToken` is similar to Guice's `TypeLiteral` class, but with one important difference: it supports non-reified types such as `T`, `List<T>` or even `List<? extends Number>`; while `TypeLiteral` does not. `TypeToken` is also serializable and offers numerous additional utility methods.

Can you get the reified type of a field using `TypeToken`? In other words, how can I do the following in Guava?

```
import org.junit.Test;
import com.google.inject.TypeLiteral;
public class FieldTypeTest {
    public static class A<T> {
        T a;
    }
    public static class B {
        A<String> b;
    }

    @Test
    public void testTypeToken() throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException {
        TypeLiteral<?> reifiedA = TypeLiteral.get(B.class).getFieldType(B.class.getDeclaredField("b"));
        assertEquals(String.class, reifiedA.getFieldType(reifiedA.getRawType().getDeclaredField("a")).getRawType());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my head, not verified

```
Type t = B.class.getDeclaredField("b").getGenericType();
Class<?> p = TypeToken.of(t).resolve(
        /* T */  A.getTypeParameters()[0]).getRawType();
// p should be String.class
```

Comment: Thanks, getGenericType() and resolve() is what I needed.

  TypeToken<?> reifiedA = TypeToken.of(B.class).resolveType(B.class.getDeclaredField("b").getGenericType());
  assertEquals(String.class, reifiedA.resolveType(reifiedA.getRawType().getDeclaredField("a").getGenericType()).getRawType());

Comment: This answer deserves +50! I was looking for this for 3 days and you saved my life!